# why is both types of oxides (Eo2 and Eo) of group 16 acidic?

Tags: oxidation-state

the oxidation state of E in Eo2 and Eo3 is +4 and +6 respectively ...then how can both of them be acidic ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All elements E appearing in the upper and right-hand part of the table are non-metals, have a high electronegativity, and their oxides are acidic. The doublet binding O and H in E-O-H is strongly attracted by the E atom. This favors the departure of the H+ ion.